# Remove unnecessary .js and .css calls (Rt-Theme19 - themeforest)

Tags: wordpress, performance, page-load-time, render-blocking

I have a ((very)) simple WP site with the above mentioned theme.

The theme loads a ton of external .css and .js files above the fold that causes render-blocking and I am sure I don't use half of them.

The header.php only includes a few directly and most are included via the php wp_head() -tag. I am struggling to find out, which .js and .css **are in use** and which aren't. Also how to **get rid of them totally** since I feel like using 'defer' or 'async' is only solving the problem partially.

My site is http://toptand.dk. Be aware, that I currently use WP Super cache for compressing and autooptimize to further minimize render-blocking etc. which might make the header look very different. I would rather get rid of it for real.

I have read many articles about how to prevent render-blocking, but non really explains how to deal with all the crap from a WP template.

Answer (score 0):

> The theme loads a ton of external .css and .js files above the fold
>   that causes render-blocking and I am sure I don't use half of them.

This is very typical of commercial WordPress themes; such themes load many files, as many are required for the "multipurpose" backend functions which provide short-codes, drag-and-drop features, custom post types, ecommerce, etc.

You sacrifice speed and page weight for all those features you use as well as the potential features you don't. If you need speed and a light-weight site, don't use a theme like that. You *can* go into that theme and `wp_dequeue_script` scripts and style sheets, but the features theme will break. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script

Try a simpler, lighter weight (and free) theme from https://wordpress.org/themes/ and learn how themes work https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/getting-started/ in order to get features you want without all the extra code.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. However, I am only working with SEO and this is (unfortunately) the theme the webdesigner chose to go for and starting over would be a big setback.

I am looking to do the best I can for this site, but with the excisting theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize Chrome Dev Tools' Audits tab.

> I am struggling to find out, which .js and .css are in use and which
>   aren't

Upon selecting the Audits tab, include Network Utilization based on necessity but mandatorily check Web Page Performance option. Once the selection is done, either click on Audit Present State or Reload and audit.

Once the process is complete, the results will provide inputs on the number of unused CSS rules. This will give you an idea about the unused CSS.

[image]

> Also how to get rid of them totally since I feel like using 'defer' or
>   'async' is only solving the problem partially.

The recent version of Chrome (59) has brought in a new feature called Coverage (you can find this under More Tools inside the dev tools). This helps in understanding the percentage of the CSS being used in the current page and clicking on one of the results redirects to the code and marks the portions of non-executed code in red and the executed ones in green.

[image]

[image]

These inputs should help you optimize your assets and remove the unused code.

Hope this helps!